# Virto Commerce Azure Deployment connection attempt failed

Tags: azure, e-commerce, azure-deployment, virtocommerce

I'm trying to deploy a custom version of VirtoCommerce to the Azure cloud and I'm having some trouble with it.
When I try to load the website i run into a

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond <ip>:9200
```

These are the last few lines of the SchedulerConsole log

```
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO] VirtoCommerce.ScheduleService.Trace Error: 0 : VirtoCommerce.Scheduling.Jobs.GenerateSearchIndexWork#3e32cbe9-b912-4901-bedb-7604a4ab0616 Trace VirtoCommerce.Search.Providers.Elastic.ElasticSearchException: Failed to remove indexes. URL:xpmarket-search.cloudapp.net:9200 ---> PlainElastic.Net.OperationException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 137.117.213.124:9200
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at PlainElastic.Net.ElasticConnection.ExecuteRequest(String method, String command, String jsonData)
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at PlainElastic.Net.ElasticConnection.ExecuteRequest(String method, String command, String jsonData)
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at PlainElastic.Net.ElasticConnection.Delete(String command, String jsonData)
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at VirtoCommerce.Search.Providers.Elastic.ElasticClient`1.Delete(DeleteCommand deleteCommand) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Extensions\Search\ElasticSearchProvider\ElasticClient.cs:line 129
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at VirtoCommerce.Search.Providers.Elastic.ElasticSearchProvider.RemoveAll(String scope, String documentType) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Extensions\Search\ElasticSearchProvider\ElasticSearchProvider.cs:line 477
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at VirtoCommerce.Search.Providers.Elastic.ElasticSearchProvider.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Extensions\Search\ElasticSearchProvider\ElasticSearchProvider.cs:line 562
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at VirtoCommerce.Search.Providers.Elastic.ElasticSearchProvider.RemoveAll(String scope, String documentType) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Extensions\Search\ElasticSearchProvider\ElasticSearchProvider.cs:line 490
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Search.SearchIndexController.Prepare(String scope, String documentType, Boolean rebuild) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Core\CommerceFoundation\Search\SearchIndexController.cs:line 91
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at VirtoCommerce.Scheduling.Jobs.GenerateSearchIndexWork.Execute(IJobContext context) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Extensions\Jobs\VirtoCommerceJobs\GenerateSearchIndexWork.cs:line 17
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO]    at VirtoCommerce.Scheduling.JobActivityTool.ControlledExecution(IJobActivity activity, TraceContext traceContext, Action`1 audit, IDictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Users\Tiago\Documents\xpmarketplace\src\Extensions\Jobs\SchedulingLib\JobActivityTool.cs:line 32
[03/16/2015 17:45:23 > 62130d: INFO] VirtoCommerce.ScheduleService.Trace Stop: 0 : VirtoCommerce.Scheduling.Jobs.GenerateSearchIndexWork#3e32cbe9-b912-4901-bedb-7604a4ab0616 Finished with Error! Duration=0m. 21s. 66
[03/16/2015 17:45:27 > 62130d: INFO] VirtoCommerce.ScheduleService.Trace Verbose: 0 : TRACE|3/16/2015 5:45:27 PM|JobScheduler|SchedulerProcess-ApartmentIteration|||Iterating 5 Jobs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Elastic Search Server is not running, can't open "137.117.213.124:9200". Which version of VC are you trying to deploy?

We had a small issue with not enough space allocated by default when elastic search was created. Here is the fix: https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-community/commit/213de23cc023cc8da8983daba188d08c2de3c2a6

Basically make sue that size is set to the new value and redeploy elastic search.

Comment: It's the version 1.13.
The problem is fixed now with your suggestion.
Thanks